# PHP form/posting error

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

ok i am having a slight problem with my posting script. Everything works great except for when i type in a phrase with like an apostrophe, example "Here's my title" wont post, put "Heres my title" will post. Not sure why this is. Maybe the strip tags i really dont know, what should i do? When it doesnt work i get thet bottom error message

```
} else {
if(isset($_POST['what'])&&isset($_POST['when'])&&isset($_POST['where'])&&isset($_POST['details'])&&isset($_POST['sponsored_by'])&&isset($_POST['collegeId'])){

$what = nl2br(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($_POST['what'])))));

$where = nl2br(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($_POST['where'])))));

$when = nl2br(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($_POST['when'])))));

$sponsored_by = nl2br(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($_POST['sponsored_by'])))));

$details = nl2br(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($_POST['details'])))));
    $collegeId = intval($_POST["collegeId"]);
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){

$username = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim(($_SESSION['username'])))));
        $query = "select id, Name from users where username='$username' and activated = 1";
        $doQuery = mysql_query($query);
        if(mysql_num_rows($doQuery)>0){
            $results = mysql_fetch_array($doQuery);
            $userName = $results['Name'];
            $email = $username;
            $id = $results['id'];
            $query = "insert into events values(NULL,$id,$collegeId,'$what','$when','$where','$details','$sponsored_by',NOW())";
            if(mysql_query($query)) header("Location: collegeInfo.php?college=$collegeId&message=added");
            else echo "Failed to create new Event!".$query;
```

Comment: I think you should start reading some articles on programming, do some tutorials - perhaps play around with some frameworks to get a feel how an app works. SO doesn't handles tutoring very well - It is better suited for more precise questions. Take a look at http://www.laravel.com/

Answer (score 6):

U dont escape your query. Try to sanitize your inputs at least with `addslashes` or `mysql_real_escape_string`. So `stripslashes` - delete backslashes from line. Use `addslashes` to add them, instead of deleting before mysql query.

And dude, `mysql_query` is **DEPRECATED** in new php versions, please use PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: im a newb and not sure what you said there

Comment: before inserting query u must check inputs. u did it.. but in wrong way. `stripslashes` - delete all backslashes from line. `addslashes` - adds backslashes to line, making it more safe to further mysql query insert. read more about sanitizing function at http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: about PDO - read this book. it is simple, believe me. just use examples. now you are using very unsafe and old syntax and methods. try to learn now with new one. Link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: ok well when i inserted that code it posted like this: Title\'s Which is obviously what the code is supposed to do i guess, how do i hide the slashes? and also how can i make the query much safer. Also should i take out the stripslashes in my username part?

Thanks for helping, i will check out that pdo

Comment: +1 for PDO - @user1664386, please for the love of all that is secure, use PDO.